# writing all files in directory to json

Tags: php, json

I made simple text editor and now working on image upload and image manager. I have set up manager to read .json file with all images and it works ok. The problem is for php script to actually write newly added images to that json.

```
$file = "images.json";
$arr_data = array();

foreach(glob('/uploads/*') as $image) {
    $arr_data = array(
        'link' => $image,
        'tag' => 'images',
    );
}

$jsondata = file_get_contents($file);
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

array_push($arr_data,$jsondata);

$jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($file, $jsondata));
```

I am getting

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array

even tho array data is provided. How to solve this?

Comment: Easies way is to output `$arr_data` and check. And remember - if error tells you that argument is not an array - it's really not an array.

Comment: Are you starting with an empty file i.e. this one `images.json`

Comment: it displays empty array after print. and yes i have empty json file

Comment: Why build up arr_data to then clobber it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with an empty file i.e. `images.json` then the first time you run these 2 lines

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents($file);
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

the second line will change `$arr_data` into a boolean probably. As `json_decode()` will fail to convert `nothing` into an array.

So add this to initialize the file for use

```
<?php
$file = "images.json";
file_put_contents($file, '[]');  // init the file
```

You are also reusing the `$arr_data` variable so amend this also and you are overwriting the new array as well

```
$file = "images.json";
file_put_contents($file, '[]');  // init the file

$arr_data = array();

foreach(glob('/uploads/*') as $image) { 
    // amended to not reuse $arr_data 
    // ameded to not overwrite the array as you build it
    $new_arr[] = array( 'link' => $image, 'tag' => 'images');
}

$jsondata = file_get_contents($file);
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

array_push($arr_data,$new_arr);

$jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($file, $jsondata));
```

Comment: so i edited json file and added placeholder images into it. after running script it shows exactly same error and json file has been altered to null

Comment: Also spotted a variable reuse

Comment: And you were overwriting the array you were building from the glob as well